# How can I add a List<string> to an object that needs a SampleSentence not List<string>?

Tags: c#

I have this class that I use to describe a sample sentence.

```
public class SampleSentence
{
    public int SampleSentenceId { get; set; } // SampleSentenceId (Primary key)
    public int WordFormId { get; set; } // WordFormId
    public string Text { get; set; } // Text
    public int SourceId { get; set; } // SourceId
    public int StatusId { get; set; } // StatusId

    // Foreign keys
    public virtual WordForm WordForm { get; set; } // FK_SampleSentenceWordForm

    public SampleSentence()
    {
        SourceId = 1;
        StatusId = 1;
    }
}
```

and SampleSentences are part of WordForms:

```
public class WordForm
{
    public int WordFormId { get; set; } // WordFormId (Primary key)
    public int WordId { get; set; } // WordId
    public string Definition { get; set; } // Definition (length: 200)
    public int PosId { get; set; } // PosId
    public int SourceId { get; set; } // SourceId
    public int StatusId { get; set; } // StatusId

    // Reverse navigation
    public virtual System.Collections.Generic.ICollection<SampleSentence> SampleSentences { get; set; } // SampleSentence.FK_SampleSentenceWordForm
    public virtual System.Collections.Generic.ICollection<Synonym> Synonyms { get; set; } // Synonym.FK_SynonymWordForm

    // Foreign keys
    public virtual Pos Pos { get; set; } // FK_WordFormPos
    public virtual Word Word { get; set; } // FK_WordFormWord

    public WordForm()
    {
        SourceId = 1;
        StatusId = 1;
        SampleSentences = new System.Collections.Generic.List<SampleSentence>();
        Synonyms = new System.Collections.Generic.List<Synonym>();
    }
}
```

I know how to create a new WordFrom like this:

```
var wordForm = new WordForm()
                        {
                            WordId = word.WordId,
                            Definition = result.definition,
                            SampleSentences = sampleSentences
                            PosId = pos
                        };
```

But given that my SampleSentences are like this:

```
List<string> = sampleSentences
```

How can I add sampleSentences to the wordForm?

Comment: You need to convert a `List<string>` to an `ICollection<Sentence>`, right? How should *we* know how a string should be translated to a `Sentence`? Do these strings within the list refer to the `SampleSentenceId`? Then you should better use a `List<int>`, shouldn´t you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll try to make it as simple as I can:

```
//As sampleSentences are List of strings 
var newListOfSentences = new List<SampleSentence>();

foreach (string value in sampleSentences)
    {
        var newSentence = new SampleSentence();
        newSentence.Text  = value ;
        //and the others...
        newListOfSentences.Add(newSentence);
    }
```

Finally you have:

```
    SampleSentences = newListOfSentences
```

Comment: Thanks.  The new List<SampleSentence>() was the big thing that I was not sure how to do.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your list `sampleSentences` contains just the IDs of the `SampleSentence`-instances you can easily put the actual instances to your `WordForm` using this:

```
var allSentences = // .. get all SampleSentences from your DB or whatever
myWordForm.SampleSentences = allSentences
    .Where(x => sampleSentences.Select(y => Convert.ToInt32(y)).Contains(x.SampleSentenceId));
```

Anyway you should store the IDs of your instances in a `List<int>` instead of `List<string>` because the `SampleSentenceId` already *is* an integer.

Otherwise if your `samleSentences`-list refers to the `Text`-property of your `SampleSentence`-instances you can write this:

```
myWordForm.SampleSentences = allSentences.Where(x => sampleSentences.Contains(x.Text));
```